# How to remove oven baked acrylic paint from glass used for drinking?

Tags: glass, acrylic-paint

I have a clear glass mug that I painted several years ago with [`Martha Stewart multi-surface craft paint`](https://www.michaels.com/msc-multisurface-satin-acrylic-craft-paint-2oz/M10198119.html).

I would like to remove the paint as I am no longer in love with the design I made and might even consider re-painting it.

**What is the best way to remove this type of paint from glass?**

I used the following instructions to set the paint on the mug:

> **Bake-to-Cure Method**
>
> 1. Allow painted item to dry for 24 hours to be sure all layers of paint have dried.
> 2. Place project in a cool oven, as the glass must heat gradually with the oven to avoid breakage; do not place glass in a hot oven.
> 3. Set oven temperature to 350ºF.
> 4. Once temperature has reached 350ºF, allow the project to bake for 30 minutes.
> 5. After 30 minutes, turn the oven off and let glass cool down completely before removing from the oven.
> 6. Do not use for 72 hours.
>
> **Care Instructions**
> Project can be Hand washed, or cleaned in the top
> rack of a standard, non-commercial dishwasher. Do not use in
> dishwasher if it has pot scrubbing features or top jets.
>
> **Paint is permanent after air drying for 21 days or can be baked to expedite permanence.**

*Taken from PLAID FAQ ["What are the curing instructions for Martha Stewart glass and craft paint?"](https://plaidonline.com/about/faqs/general/martha-stewart-glass-paint-curing-instructions)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with a razor blade and see if you can scrape it off.

If it doesn't readily scrape off, go to chemicals (below are suggestions that work with dried acrylic paint; try one at a time, do not mix them).  The procedure for all of these:

- Cover the painted area with several layers of paper towel saturated in the chemical.
- Wrap that with plastic wrap and rubber bands to seal it against the glass and minimize evaporation (don't leave any of the paper towel exposed).
- Set it on a surface that won't be affected by the chemical you're using (avoid wooden or painted or finished surfaces; plastic or glass is a safer bet).
- Use common sense and follow directions for personal safety (good ventilation, wear gloves and eye protection).
- Let it soak under the paper towel for 30 minutes to an hour.  Then see if the paint has softened enough to wipe or scrape it off.
- If it doesn't seem to be affected, try again with another chemical.  If it helped but there is still residual paint, repeat the process (try a different chemical if the result is unimpressive).

First chemicals to try (the least nasty; pick one):

- Household ammonia (full strength)
- Isopropyl alcohol, 91% - 99% (may need to shop around for a drug store that carries it at this strength)
- Denatured alcohol (available in the paint section of your hardware store)
- Goof Off (Pro Strength Remover or Paint Splatter Remover if varieties are available)

Second (nastier) group (outside is better; away from open flames or sources of sparks); most of these are available in the paint section of your hardware store:

- Acetone
- Lacquer thinner
- Paint stripper (one containing methylene chloride and/or methyl ethyl ketone [MEK] is likely to work well)
- Mineral spirits / paint thinner is something you may have on hand.  I don't know how well it will work, but if you don't have any of the other chemicals, give it a try.

Note that there are "green" versions of some of these products; many of them water-based.  I don't know which of those will work on dried acrylic or how well.

Some of these chemicals will evaporate pretty fast.  Even with plastic wrap, the paper towel may start to dry out in less than 30-60 minutes, so check it.

If you use any of these chemicals, clean the glass surface with alcohol and let it dry.  Then wash it with soapy water (running it through the dishwasher after the alcohol has dried is fine).

Comment: Thanks for this! Do you have any suggested razor blade types? I only have exacto-knives at home. Would this work or is there a better tool for scraping that you have in mind or have used with success before? Also how worried do I have to be with creating scratches on the glass?

Comment: @Wimateeka, a razor blade is how paint is removed from windows when you paint their trim.  Apply pressure across the glass (parallel with it), into the edge of the paint, so you're cutting or peeling the paint rather than pressing the blade into the glass.  I was envisioning a single edge razor blade that would be laid flat on the glass in the tall direction.  But on something round like a glass, that might be easier if the blade is held in a fixture, and it would be a good idea to use protective gloves to avoid slicing yourself if the glass or blade slips.  (cont'd)

Comment: It might be safer and easier to use any kind of utility or hobby blade and go up and down the glass.  It just wouldn't remove more than a tiny sliver each pass, so it would take a lot of scraping to clean off all the paint.

Comment: Xacto knife worked like a charm, just needed some elbow grease and patience. It did not scratch the glass and I didn't have to use chemicals :)